# Cannot create cim session with Cimsession.Create

Tags: c#, uwp

I cannot create a cim session using CimSession.Create(). I am also using UWP and running with admin privileges when debugging

Code:

```
try
    {
        CimSession cimSession = CimSession.Create("localhost");
        IEnumerable<CimInstance> enumeratedInstances = 
            cimSession.EnumerateInstances(@"root\cimv2", "Win32_Process");
        foreach (CimInstance cimInstance in enumeratedInstances)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", cimInstance.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (CimException ex) 
    { 
        // Handle the exception as appropriate.
        // This example prints the message.
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
    }
```

I get the a message like this:

The cim resource could not be created

And with further investigation I think it’s referring to a access denied error

Comment: Any updates about this?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are trying to access the `localhost` in UWP apps using the PowerShell API. There are two possible reasons for this behavior.

The first reason might be that you need to to enable the local loopback of the UWP app on your device.

To enable loopback use this command:

```
c:\>checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=<package family name>
```

To disable loopback use this command:

```
c:\>checknetisolation loopbackexempt -d -n=<package family name>
```

More information here: [Enable loopback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#loopback).

If enabling the loopback does not work, another possible reason for your issue is that UWP doesn't support calling the PowerShell API in your app. You might need to call it in a console app and launch it from the UWP app.  You could refer to Stefan Wick's blog here:[UWP with Desktop Extension](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/)